# C++: static member of template singleton class doesn't get compiled/linked

Tags: c++, templates, static, singleton, specialization

I implemented a singleton class in c++ using double checked lock(with safe locks), it works. Then I try to convert it into template version, like this:

```
// singleton.h
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
template<typename T>
struct singleton {
    ~singleton() {}
    static singleton<T>* getInstance(std::mutex& m);
    static std::atomic<singleton<T>*> m_instance; // this is the problem.
};

template<typename T>
singleton<T> * singleton<T>::getInstance(std::mutex& m) {
    auto temp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if (temp == nullptr) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
        temp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        if (temp == nullptr) {
            temp = new singleton();
            m_instance.store(temp, std::memory_order_release);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Then in a .cpp file I wish to use this class. Note the storage of `static std::atomic<singleton<T>*> m_instance` needs to exist in my .cpp file, so I tried this:

```
struct M {
    int m_i;
    static std::mutex m;
};

std::atomic<singleton<M>*> singleton<M>::m_instance; // error:

nullity) {
    auto instance1 = singleton<M>::getInstance(M::m);
    auto instance2 = singleton<M>::getInstance(M::m);
}
```

The line of `m_instance` definition reports:

```
template specialization requires 'template<>'
std::atomic<singleton<M>*> singleton<M>::m_instance;
```

How to fix this syntax error? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to explicitly specialize the static data member, just define it for the primary template itself (in the header file):

```
template<typename T>
std::atomic<singleton<T>*> singleton<T>::m_instance{nullptr};
```

Alternatively mark `m_instance` in the class template definition as `inline` (since C++17) and add the `{nullptr}` initialization there. (Beware that you must initialize explicitly to `nullptr`. The default constructor of `std::atomic` does not perform proper initialization before C++20.)

There is no need to add anything in the source file.

---

The whole thing is extremely redundant though, since the compiler will add the whole locking mechanism to dynamic initialization of a local static storage duration variable anyway (since C++11). You don't need to do anything manually. The common approach is to define the singleton as

```
static auto& getInstance() {
    static singleton<T> instance;
    return instance;
}
```

without a static data member, or if the dynamic storage duration is important to you

```
static auto& getInstance() {
    static auto instance = std::make_unique<singleton<T>>();
    return *instance;
}
```

Comment: OP: Google threadsafe initialisers for more insight about why this answer is correct.